# Foliation with single leaf coming from frobenius theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

I was reading the Ambrose -- Singer theorem [2] and I came up with a question. The theorem ends with a situation like the following:

Let $M$ be a connected manifold modeled on the banach space $\mathbf V$ and $E \subseteq \mathrm{T}M$ an involutive subbunde, with fibers of type $\mathbf E$ ($\mathbf E \subseteq \mathbf V$ is complemented in $\mathbf V$). By the frobenius theorem, given some point $x \in M$, we can find a maximal integral connected manifold $N$ passing from $x$ [1], that is, a submanifold $N \subseteq M$: the natural inclusion $\jmath : N \longrightarrow M$ is an immersion and the tangent map $\mathrm{T}\jmath$ induces a VB--isomorphism between $\mathrm{T}N$ and $\jmath^*E$.

The theorem proceeds by proving $N = M$ (that is, the maximal integral manifold equals the initial manifold as sets). Then it asserts that the fibers of $E$ and $\mathrm{T}M$ are isomorphic, otherwise the maximal integral manifold would not be all of $M$ [3]

How can we prove the following implication:
$$M = N \Longrightarrow \text{distribution $E$ is trivial,
with fibers isomorphic to $\mathrm{T}M$}$$ 
I cannot find any general proof to this, or any counterexample (actually $M$ is a principal bundle $P$ on connected base having the holonomy group $\Phi(u)$ as structure group, $u \in P$).

Even worse the same argument is used in the infinite dimensional case i 've found at [5]

In the case that $M$ is second countable and finite dimensional: 
Say that $M = N$ and $E$ is not trivial. Then at any $m \in N$, we can find a local chart $(U, \varphi)$ of $M$ over $m$, a split of $\mathbf V = \mathbf E \times \mathbf F$, such that $\varphi: U \longrightarrow U_{\mathbf E} \times U_{\mathbf F} \subseteq \mathbf E \times \mathbf F$ and for any fixed $y \in U_{\mathbf F}$ the map
$$ U_{\mathbf E} \ni z \longmapsto \psi_y(z) \;\stackrel{def}= \varphi^{-1}(z,y) \in M$$
is an integral manifold locally. Then the maximal integral manifold (which is endowed with its own differentiable structure) passes from every distinct plaque $\psi_y$, $y \in U_{\mathbf F}$, and hence it is made non-second countable space. It is known that the maximal integral manifold [4] as the leaf of a foliation must be second countable. This is a contradiction.

But what in the case that $M$ is not second countable or infinite dimensional?

My references are a bit standard:
[1] Serge Lang, Differential and Riemannian Manifolds 
[2] Kobayashi - Nomizu, Foundations of differential geometry 
[3] Shlomo Sternberg, Lectures on differential geometry 
[4] Cesar Camacho, Geometric theory of foliations 
and the article is the following: 
[5] Vassiliou, On the infinite dimensional holonomy theorem

Answer (score 1):

You're reading very sophisticated material, but this point truly is evident. Remember that for every $p\in N$, $T_pN = E_p$ (by definition of integral manifold). so, if $N=M$, this means that $T_pN = T_pM$, and so $E_p=T_pM$. This of course means that $E=TM$.

Comment: This is what i thought initially, but then i started doubting. Can a set relation $M=N$ lead to a tangent space relation? My problem came up from the fact that $M$ and $N$ are the same sets with differentiable structures not known to be identical a priori. $N$ is immersed through $\jmath$ _onto_ $M$, but does this imply it has the same tangent spaces? Dont i need to prove first that $\jmath$ is open?
As i was looking for information around the net, i imagined of a situation (even if a bit impossible)  "what if $\jmath$ is like immersing the long line into the plane?".

Comment: Well, no bizarre point-set topology going on here :) The point to ponder is this: What's the dimension of $N$? If it's less than $\dim M$, you can end up with a *dense* immersed submanifold, but you can never have all of $M$.

Comment: And in the case that $M$ is modeled on a banach (possible nonseparable) space, what can one say? Is it trivial in the same way?

Comment: I only know about Ambrose-Singer in the finite-dimensional case, so I don't even have a clue what (if anything) happens in the Banach case. If the integral manifold *is* the ambient manifold, there's nothing to discuss, regardless. But I am not going to ponder this ...